# PDFSharp write on more pages

Tags: c#

I want to write a PDF on more than one page.
I already created 4 pages, but the program does a cut
on the first page. So the pages 2,3,4 are empty.

How to fix that?

Code:

```
string outFileName = "Vertrag/vertrag.txt";
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    foreach (string inFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles("schnippsel", "DE*.txt"))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFileName))
        {
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}

TextReader readFile = new StreamReader("Vertrag/vertrag.txt");

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage pdfPage = pdf.AddPage();
PdfPage pdfPage2 = pdf.AddPage();
PdfPage pdfPage3 = pdf.AddPage();
PdfPage pdfPage4 = pdf.AddPage();

XGraphics graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);
XGraphics graph2 = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage2);
XGraphics graph3 = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage3);
XGraphics graph4 = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage4);
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);

string line = null;
int yPoint = 0;

while (true)
{
    line = readFile.ReadLine();
    if (line == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {

        yPoint = yPoint + 40;
        graph.DrawString(line, font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(40, yPoint, 40, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft);
    }
}
pdf.Save("Vertrag/vertrag.pdf");

readFile.Close();
readFile = null;
```

I must write more details here :P

It looks like that:

Page1:
Hello, my name is
Page 2:
Page 3:
Page 4:

Comment: it seems that you have a graph for each page. Have you tried using `graph2.DrawString(...)` ?